# Python - split list element containing character (e.g. /,[]) and create new elements

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like:

```
test = ['bla bla','affect /affected / affecting']
print(test)
```

and I would like to create new elements in the list by separating the ones that are one element but separated through the "/" symbol.

E.g. desired output in this case:

```
test_new = ['bla bla','affect','affected','affecting']
```

How can I do that?

EDIT: The list can have multiple elements, and not all have the "/" symbol

Comment: Is `test` always a list with exactly one item in it…?

Comment: *"....by separating the ones that are **one element** but..."*. It would be nice to post an example that contains elements that are not *one element* to demonstrate what you want to do in the most general of cases.

Comment: No the list can have multiple items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and `split` on `'/'` and `strip` to remove spaces (assuming you have multiple strings, being a list):

```
[j.strip() for i in test for j in i.split('/')]
# ['affect', 'affected', 'affecting']
```

Comment: I get an error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: If test is a list (as in your question), this works fine @adrCoder

Answer (score 0):

```
testEntry=test[0]
testEntry=test.replace(' ','')
test=testEntry.split('/')
```

Comment: I want to do it on the whole list not only one element. Some elements may not contain "/"

Comment: Please do not post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes.